# Compress image with Magick.NET doesn't reduce too much

Tags: c#, magick.net

```
var fileName = Path.Combine(filePath, $"{nameOnly}{ext}");

using (var stream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create))
{
    await formFile.CopyToAsync(stream);
    stream.Position = 0;
    ImageOptimizer optimizer = new ImageOptimizer() {
        OptimalCompression = true,
        IgnoreUnsupportedFormats =true
    };
    optimizer.Compress(stream);
}
```

I have an image 3.6MB and after compressed, it's 3.32MB, still too big.

I am looking for a size below 1MB.

Do we have any other way to future reduce its size?
I don't want to re-size btw.

Comment: What type of image are you storing? For instance JPG supports a quality: lower quality = smaller file

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39750795/reduce-image-size-imagemagic

Comment: @HansKeﬆing look at my code, it's already same with the article you provided. I am asking further reducing .

Comment: @HansKeﬆing I am thinking of jpg, png