# ImageMagick convert tif to png or jpeg producing larger images

Tags: imagemagick, png, tiff, imagemagick-convert

I have a lot of tif images I would like to convert to a web friendly format. Ive been playing a little bit with imagemagick (and a couple other libraries) to try to convert them, but the resulting image is a lot larger than the original, uncompressed image.

For example:

```
1.tif - 348.2kB
1.png - 781.7 kB
1.jpg - 429.1 kb

2.tif - 49.8 kB
2.png - 76.2 kB
2.jpg 900.4 kB

3.tif 7.7 kB
3.png 21.4 kB
3.jpg 191.3 kB
```

The command im using:

```
convert *.tif -set filename: "%t" %[filename:].jpg
```

Im not an expert, but I dont understand how passing from an uncompressed source image to a compressed one makes the size explode. Any idea of what is happening?

After running the proposed command

```
identify -format "%f: size: %B, compression: %C\n" *png *tif *jpg
```

I get the following output

```
00000001.png: size: 104522, compression: Zip
00000002.png: size: 23565, compression: Zip
00000003.png: size: 58936, compression: Zip
00000001.tif: size: 74122, compression: Group4
00000002.tif: size: 10946, compression: Group4
00000003.tif: size: 29702, compression: Group4
00000001.jpg: size: 1011535, compression: JPEG
00000002.jpg: size: 226068, compression: JPEG
00000003.jpg: size: 457045, compression: JPEG
```

Comment: CCITT Group 4 (aka T.6) is *very* efficient for black/white (FAX) data. JPEG is inefficient for such data. 1 bit PNG with maximum compression should be close in size, but I don't think there's anything unexpected with what you see here. Instead it's the assumption that the original is uncompressed that is wrong.

Comment: ok, thanks, thats good to know too. how can i set maximum compression for png? I know that 1 bit is set with the option -depth 1 (and it barely changes the size of the resulting image)

Comment: Perhaps [ImageMagick: Lossless max compression for PNG?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27267073/imagemagick-lossless-max-compression-for-png)?

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to say what is happening without seeing your images - not all software uses the same compression method, or quality and some formats, such as PNG are lossless.

As a first attempt, try running this command to check the filename, file size, compression type of all your images:

```
identify -format "%f: size: %B, compression: %C\n" *png *tif *jpg
```

**Sample Output**

```
zHZB9.png: size: 1849, compression: Zip
result.tif: size: 290078, compression: None
z.tif: size: 213682, compression: LZW
sky.jpg: size: 88162, compression: JPEG
z.jpg: size: 8122, compression: JPEG
```

Now you can see the numbers you can decide what you want to address. So, to get a list of all the compression types you can use:

```
identify -list compress
```

**Sample Output**

```
B44A
B44
BZip
DWAA
DWAB
DXT1
DXT3
DXT5
Fax
Group4
JBIG1
JBIG2
JPEG2000
JPEG
LosslessJPEG
Lossless
LZMA
LZW
None
Piz
Pxr24
RLE
RunlengthEncoded
WebP
ZipS
Zip
Zstd
```

Now, you can experiment, e.g. by making some TIFFs with different settings:

```
convert -size 1024x768 gradient: 1.tif
convert -size 1024x768 gradient: -compress lzw 2.tif
convert -size 1024x768 gradient: -compress jpeg  3.tif
convert -size 1024x768 gradient: -compress jpeg  -quality 40 4.tif
```

Now check:

```
1.tif: size: 1573138, compression: None
2.tif: size: 6316, compression: LZW
3.tif: size: 17520, compression: JPEG
4.tif: size: 9830, compression: JPEG
```

Comment: I updated my question with the output of the command you suggested. Ive tried experimenting as you suggested converting the tif to different compressions, but they all seem to weigh more than the original. Another weird thing is that a colleague opened one of the images with photoshop, and it says it weighs 1 MB. even though it says it the terminal its just a few kB. And after exporting it to any format, it weighs more than the original!

Comment: Can you please share the exact command you used and at least one original input and output file - you may need to use Google Drive, or Dropbox if imgur won't accept TIFFs.

Comment: yeah, of course: https://www.dropbox.com/s/mk0cl0o8u5aro8o/image_files.zip?dl=0

Comment: ah, and the command is the one in the question, ```convert *.tif -set filename: "%t" %[filename:].jpg``` and the same with png

Comment: Your TIFFs are one-bit faxes. JPG won't work well, but you can make a one-bit PNG image from them and the size should be similar.

Comment: How? Ive tried ```convert 00000001.tif -depth 1 00000001_1bit.png``` And its a little bit smaller than the png with the original command, but still a lot larger than the tiff image

Comment: I don't know any way within the confines of the PNG specification to make an efficient representation of bi-level Group4-compressed data. Maybe Fred @fmw42 has an idea?